# Sequelize.sync({force: true}) keeps obsolete model schema

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

My nodejs/sequelizejs (5.7.6)/postgres (11.2) app has a socketlist model which has been recently updated as following:

```
const SocketList = db.define('socketlist', {
    user_ids: {type: Sql.ARRAY(Sql.INTEGER),
    },
    fort_token: { 
      type: Sql.STRING      
    },
    server_id: {type: Sql.STRING
    },
}, {
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
          {
            fields: ['fort_token']
          },
          {
            fields: ['server_id']
          },
        ]   
});
```

I am using the `sync` to create db tables:

```
db.sync({force:true})
    .then((res) => {
        console.log("db done!");
        console.log(res);  
    }); //create db
```

The problem is that the `socketlist` table created is still based on the old schema which has already been updated and I have no clue where the `sync` cached the obsolete schema code. I tried to delete the whole db or the table but the result is always the same - old and obsolete schema. The `sync` has been working fine until now. Is it a bug with `sequelizejs`? What is wrong with the code?

Also the `findOne()` uses the obsolete schema as well, as indicated by console output:

```
Socketio server is initialized
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "user_id", "socket_id", "event_id", "server_id", "active" FROM "socketlists" AS "socketlist" WHERE "socketlist"."fort_token" = '12345678901234567890' LIMIT 1;
```

I removed and re-installed the `sequelize` and the problem remains.

Here is the db connection:

```
const Sql = require("sequelize");
const db = new Sql('myDB', 'postgres', `${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}`, {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    port:5433,
} );
```

Here is the old (obsolete) SocketList schema:

```
const Sql = require("sequelize");
//const Op = Sql.Op;
const db = require("../startup/db");
const Joi = require('joi');

const SocketList = db.define('socketlist', {
    id: {type: Sql.INTEGER,
         primaryKey:true,
         autoIncrement: true,
         min: 1
    },
    socket_id: {type: Sql.STRING,
                min: 1
    },
    event_id: {type: Sql.INTEGER,
               min: 1
    },
    server_id: {type: Sql.STRING
    },
    active: {type: Sql.BOOLEAN,
             defaultValue: true,
    },
}, {
    timestamps: false
 }, { 
        indexes: [
          {
            //socket_id
            fields: ['socket_id']
          },
          {
            fields: ['active']
          },
          {
            fields: ['server_id']
          },
          {
            fields: ['event_id']
          },
        ]   
}); 

module.exports.SocketList = SocketList;
```

Comment: can you post your old schema? model and are you able to post your full db connection code?

Comment: Just added more info to the post.

Comment: My bad. I found that the SocketList was required from another subdir which points to an obsolete definition. The problem disappears after pointing to the current one.

Answer (score 0):

I will contribute about that because I have found a simple solution.
Try DROP the scheme and start again the server with force:true.

For example, to DROP the scheme on postgresql:
**DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA public;**